# How can I determine the previously selected field in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using an application with an MSSQL database in the back-end. 
I have created a stored procedure in SQL and the application allows for me to link the procedure to a button. For example, I have a form in the application which shows all of the data from table1 and I want the stored procedure to manipulate the data in table1 when the button is pressed.

This leaves me with the issue: How on earth is the stored procedure going to know which record in table1 to manipulate?

I want to only affect the CURRENT record which is being viewed in the application when the button is pressed.

I presume that whenever the form is opened, the application will run an SQL select query to show the data in table1 for the first record and then when the user enters a recordID, the application would run a select command to display the data for said record. Therefore, I would expect that what I am trying to achieve can be done by looking at the most recent select record on the table.

Is this possible?

Comment: No, that's not how it should (or could) work. Your table should have a primary key column, and you should pass the value of the PK column to the stored procedure.

Comment: Yes exactly. But a table is filled with lots of records with lots of different primary keys. I want to know how the SP knows which PK to manipulate when the button is pressed. How does it know which record the user has open on the screen?

Comment: It doesn't know, the application that's displaying the screen should pass the PK value when it calls the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You application should pass the primary key value to the stored procedure. 
There are many options as to how to communicate with your database. Assuming that you're using .NET as a framework for your application you can use Entity Framework or for the simplicity of this example you could use SqlCommand class

in your button's click handler add the following code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("....your connection string...")) {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_yourStoredProc", conn)) {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intYourRecordsID;

      conn.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      //or SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //if you want to return data
    }
}
```

Your stored procedure might look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_yourStoredProc
@id int
AS
    /*...do whatever you want with your passed @id*/
GO
```